# Tslint: Max-line-length not fixed by prettier

Tags: import, formatting, visual-studio-code, tslint, prettier

I'm using VSCode with prettier plugin and typescript and also tslint.

Leaving aside the convenience to use this configuration, I get a

```
[tslint] Exceeds maximum line length of 120 (max-line-length)
```

For a line like this:

```
import { MyComponent } from "../../some_very_long_path";
```

I've prettier configured with a print-width of 100, so I was expecting that on `Format Document` this line would be refactored into something like this:

```
import { MyComponent } 
  from "../../some_very_long_path";
```

or like this:

```
import {
  MyComponent
} from "../../some_very_long_path";
```

But it is not. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 24):

The documentation says *printWidth*. The documentation link is [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width)

```
printWidth: 120
```

Probably this should solve the problem.

Comment: The documentation specifically says printWidth is not the same: "In other words, don’t try to use printWidth as if it was ESLint’s max-len"

Answer (score 8):

You can add [exception for specific regex](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/max-line-length/).
Prettier will have the lead for managing imports and exports, since it has a [special way to deal with them](https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#imports).

```
// edit your tslint.json
"max-line-length": [
     true, 
    { 
        "limit": 140, 
        "ignore-pattern": "^import |^export {(.*?)}" 
    }
],
```

Answer (score 2):

Prettier is not breaking down imports and the best thing you can do is to remove all the stylistic errors (including the max-line-length) from tslint rules and let Prettier to handle those and tslint the code related ones.